# UITableViewCell constraints not seen in iOS 8. How do I mitigate this?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to understand why the constraints I have put in place on the Storyboard for my different labels in my cell aren't being done. This is important because my height is dynamic.

I have had this problem for the past 2 days and it's driving me up the wall. No, `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is not how I want to do this.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    var cell = self.feed.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("post") as PostCell

    var post = self.posts[indexPath.row]

    cell.name.text = post.name
    cell.timestamp.text = post.timestamp
    cell.postBody.text = post.body

    println("\(cell.name.constraints())")
    println("\(cell.postBody.constraints())")

    cell.contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()     
    cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

    cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(feed.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell.bounds))

    cell.setNeedsLayout()
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    var height = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingExpandedSize).height

    height += 1.0

    return height
}
```

When I print the constraints set for `cell.postBody` I get `[]`. However, I have 5 constraints. A trailing space to Superview, leading space to Superview, Bottom space to Superview Equals 4, and 2 Top Spaces to 2 different labels Equals 8.

If it isn't possible for my code to see the constraints via the Storyboard, how do I programmatically set these 5 constraints

**Updated way I'm doing it:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = self.feed.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("post") as PostCell

    var post = self.posts[indexPath.row]

    cell.name.text = post.name
    cell.timestamp.text = post.timestamp
    cell.postBody.text = post.body

    if cachedHeights[post.id] == nil && cell.bounds.height != 0.0 {
        cachedHeights[post.id] = cell.bounds.height
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    var post = posts[indexPath.row]

    if cachedHeights[post.id] != nil {
        return cachedHeights[post.id]!
    } else {
        return 70
    }
}
```

The problem is, I'm not sure cell.bounds.height is completely accurate. In that I mean, I think it is using the height of a previous large cell sometimes (perhaps from the cell it dequeued for the new one.)

Comment: Is there a particular reason to avoid automatic dimensioning?

Comment: Automatica Dimensioning currently has a bug that affects scrolling (scrolling becomes jumpy) when you reload any part of your data but aren't at the very top of the UITableView. Unless, I can use it and ping the height the Automatic Dimensioning figures out for each cell and then cache that value and use that later, but I'm not sure thats possible.

Comment: I'm familiar with that bug, and it is possible to do what you're thinking. You can cache the auto-sized height before returning from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and return that cached height in `tableview:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`.  (The bug falls back to using the row's estimated height, instead of the known actual height.)  But if you set your `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` to a really accurate value to begin with, you can avoid needing to work around the bug.

Comment: How would I ping to get the dynamic height for the cell from cellForRowAtIndexPath? I don't think I ever get a particularly accurate value.

Comment: I just tried to get the value of the height, but I get `0.0` whenever I call `cell.bounds.height`

Comment: Yes, you'll get 0 for all the initial cells, until they start getting reused.  From that point on, you'll get the cell's auto-sized height.

Answer (score 1):

The constraints aren't on the labels.  That's why their `constraints` property returns an empty array.

You'll find the constraints on the labels' superview, `cell.contentsView`.

You can skip the calls to `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` and `updateConstraintsIfNeeded` as layoutSubviews will call `updateConstraintsIfNeeded`.

**The old approach I used before switching to self-sizing cells:**

I don't have any swift code, but here's some old code from an app before I switched over to self-sizing cells.  It (implicitly) uses the constraints placed on the labels in the storyboard cell.  The only thing different I did is caching the sizing cell.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static LeftDetailTableViewCell *cell;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    });

    // configure the cell for this indexPath

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Set the sizing cell's width to the tableview's width

    cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell.bounds));

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    // get the fitting size

    CGSize s = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return s.height + 1.0;
}
```

**Update:**

Here's the code I'm using now, for self-sized cells in iOS 8.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BIBLETableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell adjustSizeToMatchWidth:CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.frame)];

    [self configureAccessoryTypeForCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell adjustConstraintsToMatchSeparatorInset:self.tableView.separatorInset];

    [self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

    return cell;
}
```

My subclassed cell has:

```
- (void)adjustSizeToMatchWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    // Workaround for visible cells not laid out properly since their layout was
    // based on a different (initial) width from the tableView.

    CGRect rect = self.frame;
    rect.size.width = width;
    self.frame = rect;

    // Workaround for initial cell height less than auto layout required height.

    rect = self.contentView.bounds;
    rect.size.height = 99999.0;
    rect.size.width = 99999.0;
    self.contentView.bounds = rect;
}

- (void)adjustConstraintsToMatchSeparatorInset:(UIEdgeInsets)inset
{
    if (self.leadingMargins)
    {
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.leadingMargins)
        {
            constraint.constant = inset.left;
        }
    }

    if (self.trailingMargins)
    {
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.trailingMargins)
        {
            constraint.constant = self.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator ? 0.0f : inset.left;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the method you hinted at using though in the comments, right? I am now getting the auto-sized heights, but in my println, they don't seem to be accurate.

Comment: No, the method I posted is my old pre-self-sizing approach that you prefer to use.  I've completely switched over to self-sizing cells, and don't do any height calculations at all.  All I did was to average the cell's self-sized height, and plug that value in for my `estimatedRowHeight`.  Because the estimate is close to the dynamic height, I don't see it jump anymore.

Comment: I am still getting jumps when my text seems huge, I'm updating the parent with the code I just made. Is it accurate?

Comment: I do two things you're not doing in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  1) I set the cell's size, because its (initial) width will be the storyboard width, not the tableView width.  2)  I call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` and `updateConstraintsIfNeeded` (because my constraints change for the adaptive UI on the iPhone 6 Plus).  The height I get back is correct, for the self-sized cell.  I'll post that code so you can see how I handle auto-sizing.

Comment: I'm still getting some jumping. I know why I'm getting jumping though. I get it because when I call `cell.bounds.height` it isn't the height of the cell with my new data. It's the height of the cell that was just dequeued, which means I'm caching incorrect heights for cells. Is there a way to mitigate this, or anyway to get the force-updated height of the cell? I tried using `cell.needsUpdateConstraints()` and `cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()` but it didn't force-update the height.

Comment: Not sure, sorry.  If you can't figure out how to get the actual height, then just place the height calculation code in `tableview:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` so the actual height is returned for the estimate.  It seems contrary for auto-sizing, but that's the nature of the SDK bug, unfortunately.  Anyway, once the estimate is correct, it should stop jumping.

Comment: I fixed it! So, what I do in my cellForRowAtIndexPath is I do cache the height, but I cache the height for the dequeued cell. I'll post my code in answer if you're curious.