# iOS 8 UITableView cells jump when selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8

I have a pretty standard UITableView that uses auto resizing cells

```
// Set the height of the table view cells
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

When I push segue to a new view controller, the table view jumps to a different position. I've tried estimatedRowHeight, rowHeight, using the tableView methods, and nothing...

I've read these and nothing still really has worked. Anyone?

• [Table View Cells jump when selected on iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937827/table-view-cells-jump-when-selected-on-ios-8)

• [iOS 8 Auto cell height - didSelectRowAtIndexPath causes UItableview to jump to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598453/ios-8-auto-cell-height-didselectrowatindexpath-causes-uitableview-to-jump-to-t)

• [IOS 8 UITableView self-sizing cells jump/shift visually when a new view controller is pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370879/ios-8-uitableview-self-sizing-cells-jump-shift-visually-when-a-new-view-controll/27895188#27895188)

Comment: Have you implemented the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath:?

Comment: Yeah I have implemented it.

Comment: Could you share it? seems like the problem is there (cause the problem is whn you select una cell)

Comment: The code I posted for this answer should help.  I have no longer seen the table jump when the push segue happens (either because the bug is fixed, or my estimated height is very accurate): http://stackoverflow.com/a/28267459/4151918

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996438/jerky-scrolling-after-updating-uitableviewcell-in-place-with-uitableviewautomati/28376230?noredirect=1#comment51791456_28376230

See my answer

Answer (score 4):

It's a known issue.

I believe you'll find that the more the `estimatedRowHeight` differs from the actual height, the more the table will jump when the push segue happens.  The workaround is to use a much better estimate (or to implement `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` and return the exact height).

Comment: Could you share an example of this please?

Comment: You can use the same code you would have used in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` before self-sizing cells came along.  But I'd recommend trying to use a more accurate estimatedRowHeight, first, especially if your actual rows aren't 44 points high.  You may find that a much better estimate is a good enough workaround for the issue.